# Django entering args for call_command for custom datadump

Tags: python, django, args

I am trying to make a custom datadump for Django fixtures so I don't dump everything into one file.

here is my code that throws an error:

**extract.py**

```
def create_fixture( filename, *app_name):
    # buffer
    buf = StringIO()
    # unpacks args to list of db tables
    apps = ','.join(map(str, app_name))
    # calls dump data and adds db table to call command
    call_command('dumpdata', apps, indent=2, format='json', stdout=buf)
    # Write to file
    buf.seek(0)
    with open(Path.cwd().joinpath('main', 'fixtures', filename), 'w') as f:
        f.write(buf.read())

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Dumps database file to fixtures'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #calls function
        create_fixture('country.json','main.Country','main.Cities')
        #prints to console if successful
        self.stdout.write("Dumped Country data!")
```

If I run `python manage.py extract` in the console I get the following message:

```
CommandError: No installed app with label 'main.Country,main.Cities'
```

But if I write the code like this it works fine but does not use a function:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Dumps database file to fixtures'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        buf = StringIO()
        call_command('dumpdata', 'main.Country', 'main.Cities',indent=2, format='json', stdout=buf)
        buf.seek(0)
        with open(Path.cwd().joinpath('main', 'fixtures', 'country.json'), 'w') as f:
            f.write(buf.read())
        self.stdout.write("Dumped Country data")
```

Not sure how to unpack the args correctly and put them into the call_command function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app_name** that you are passing in **create_fixture** is tuple.
You dont need to unpack them and convert to string.

When you do this:

```
apps = ','.join(map(str, app_name))
```

You are actually converting it to list first and then joining all of its elements with **,**(comma). Which is giving you just an string **'main.Country,main.Cities'**.

just pass your tuple directly top **call_command**.

```
call_command('dumpdata', *app_name, indent=2, format='json', stdout=buf)
```

Comment: Thanks somehow dunno how I missed that after looking at the docs for *args